# How can I get this new Gaussion curvature and mean curvature?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ oriented by $\vec n$. For a fixed number $\varepsilon\neq0$, let $F:M\to\mathbb{R}^3$ be a mapping such that $F(p)=p+\varepsilon\vec n(p)$ and denote $\overline{M}=F(M)$. Knowing $\vec{x}(u,v)$ a parametrization of $M$.

> Show that 
>   $$\overline{K}(F(p))=\frac{K(p)}{J(p)},\overline{H}(F(p))=\frac{H(p)-\varepsilon K(p)}{J(p)},$$
>   where $J(p)=1-2\varepsilon H(p)+\varepsilon ^2$,$K(p)=(1-\varepsilon k_1(p))(1-\varepsilon k_2(p))$,(suppose $J \neq0$)

Could someone can teach me steps by steps?Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to represent $\vec n_u$ (the partial derivative of $\vec n$) in terms of $\vec x_u$ and $\vec x_v$? (Sorry for not replying your previous post: I forgot).

Comment: I already know how to represent $\overline{E}$,but I don't know how to represent $\overline{l}$(by second fundamental form) at $\overline{\vec{n}}(u,v)$.And what I asked in this web also bother me.